# Cannot start openerp 7 because missing module osv

Tags: odoo

Currently my openerp isntance cannot start/restart. When I run

```
$ sudo openerp-server restart
```

It says..

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/openerp-server", line 5, in <module> 
    openerp.cli.main()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/cli/__init__.py", line 51 in main __import__(m)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/modules/module.py", line 133, in load_module
    mod = imp.load_module('openerp.addons.' + module_part, f, path, descr)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/base_action_rule/__init__.py" line 23, in <module)
    import test_models
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/base_action_rule/test_models.py", line 1, in <module>
    from osv import osv, fields
ImportError: No module named osv
```

What should I do?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Go this path `/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/base_action_rule/test_models.py` and try below code.

```
import openerp
from openerp.osv import fields, osv
```

Remove this line `from osv import osv, fields`

Answer (score 0):

Usually this error comes when your configuration data is wrong.please check the configuration data.If no configuration file, then check how the server is running. is there any external addons path specified etc